# Clarify generic type in child class in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have a protocol that describes a neural network Layer:

```
protocol Layer: AnyObject {
    associatedtype NeuronType: Neuron
    var neurons: [NeuronType] { get }

    func neuron(_ neuron: NeuronType)
    func neurons(_ neurons: [NeuronType])
}
```

Also I have a metaclass that adopts this protocol:

```
class AnyLayer: Layer {
    public var neurons = [AnyNeuron]()

    public func neuron(_ neuron: AnyNeuron) { /* Some actions */ }
}
```

There is an implicit `typealias NeuronType = AnyNeuron`. However when I want to create a new class that inherits from `AnyLayer`, I cannot change the `NeuronType` generic type from `AnyNeuron` to another, even if this another type inherits from `AnyNeuron`:

```
final class InputLayer: AnyLayer {
    override var neurons = [InputNeuron]()  // Property 'neurons' with type '[InputNeuron]' cannot override a property with type '[AnyNeuron]'
}
```

Also if I change `typealias` in child class, then nothing will change:

```
final class InputLayer: AnyLayer {
    typealias NeuronType = InputNeuron  // neurons still [AnyNeuron]
}
```

I want to do this without adding any generics to `AnyLayer`. Is there a beautiful solution how can I resolve this issue and inherit class with `AnyLayer` and change generic type?

Comment: Why a subclass and not an independent class that conforms to the protocol?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for your answer! Because I need to have an opportunity to cast my subclass to AnyLayer. I do not know any way to do this without the inheritance.

Comment: If AnyLayer sets NuronType to AnyNeuron, why not just remove the associated type from Layer and make it AnyNeuron? Then you don't need inheritance. You can just use the protocol. OTOH, if you require changing the associated type, then inheritance doesn't help you (as I believe you're discovering). The issue is the associated type. Get rid of it, or get rid of inheritance. There is no "generalized existential" in Swift today. You can't do this. Go back to your actual requirements and redesign to meet those rather than this set. Start with what code *calls* this, and that will drive the types.

Comment: Note that InputLayer absolutely cannot change the type of `neurons` in this specific case, not even in theory (putting aside any current Swift-specific limitations). It's a mutable property. So if you have a `layer` of type AnyLayer (which is actually an InputLayer), I must be allowed call `layer.neurons.append(SomeOtherNeuronType())`, and that would violate InputLayer's requirements.